# Howto control custum taxonomy order?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a site with custom taxonomy.
I want to give the client the ability to control the taxonomy order.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Advanced Taxonomy Terms Order](http://www.nsp-code.com/premium-plugins/wordpress-plugins/advanced-taxonomy-terms-order/) it's a great plugin for terms order